# Understanding numpy.gradient

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, derivative

I have a time-series of voltage values recorded in `mV` every `0.02 ms`, stored as a numpy array.

If I do this,

```
dv_dt = np.gradient(v),
```

what will the units of `dv_dt` be?   Will it be some multiple of `V/s`; e.g. `mV/s`, `mV/(0.02 ms)`, etc?

My understanding is that `gradient` returns the derivative of the argument passed to it.  Is that right?

See this [related question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/202402/89374).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Watch out for the unit spacing of dt. As noted in the [documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.gradient.html) `gradient` assumes unit spacing of 1 unless you provide the sample distance by the `vararg` argument. Your case is only correct, if `dt = 1` for all datapoints.

You have to define your units by yourself. It is fine to use milliseconds but unless you do not have a good reason for it, I would use SI units (in this case seconds and Volts; which is the same as mV and ms). The gradient will have units of mV/ms or V/s.

In your case `np.gradient(v,0.02)` will give you the first order difference of the voltage signal corrected with your spacing of the time axis.

Comment: thanks for the answer.  `dt` is the same for all my datapoints -- it's 0.02 ms, like i said in the question statement -- unless i'm misunderstanding you.  with the assumption that `dt = 1`, is that referring to the spacing in the array, as in, every step of one element in the array represents one `dt`?  i'm still not clear on what the units are of the derivative in my case.

Comment: dv/dt means that you first take the derivative of v and divide it by the derivative of t. It makes a huge difference if your signal changes 1 mV in 1 millisecond or in 0.02 milliseconds. In the first case the gradient is 1 mV/ms, in the second case it is 50 mV/ms

Comment: ok, so i worked it out by hand, and coming back to this i have a better understanding of what you were trying to say.  the right call for me to make is `np.gradient(v, 0.02)`, assuming i want to keep the input array itself as it is.  the returned array -- the derivative -- is in units of V / s (not mV / s or anything else, which i guess should've been obvious, considering i submitted a dt in ms and a voltage in mV).  if you reword your answer to incorporate this, i'll accept it.